# Unable to skip running pipeline based on variable in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to force the pipeline to skip running job **whenever the project's branch is equal to develop**. I've created the custom variable name `$CURRENT_BRANCH` that gathering from predefined variable `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`

```
- export CURRENT_BRANCH=`echo ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | awk -F '/' '{print $1}'`
```

The `$CURRENT_BRANCH` will pass along the first stage and it will save in the artifact

```
- >
            if [ ${CURRENT_BRANCH} == 'feature' ]; then
                export CURRENT_BRANCH="feature"
                export FEATURE_NAME=`echo ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'` 
                echo "FEATURE_NAME=${FEATURE_NAME}" >> info.env
                echo "PROJECT_NAME=${FEATURE_NAME}" >> info.env
            else
                export CURRENT_BRANCH=${CURRENT_BRANCH}
                echo "PROJECT_NAME=${CURRENT_BRANCH}" >> info.env
            fi
        - echo "CURRENT_BRANCH=${CURRENT_BRANCH}" >> info.env
    artifacts:
        reports:
            dotenv: info.env
```

Then in the next stage until the last stage, I've tried to skip running the pipeline with `only/except` and `rules/when` for example,

```
build_image:
    image: docker:19.03
    services:
        - docker:dind
    stage: release
    only:
      variables:
        - $CURRENT_BRANCH != "develop"
```

as well as using `rules` and when condition

```
build_image:
    image: docker:19.03
    services:
        - docker:dind
    stage: release
    rules:
      - if: '$CURRENT_BRANCH == "develop"'
        when: never
```

The pipeline still running. Are there anything that I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from Gitlab docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

*`Rules` are evaluated `when` the pipeline is `created`, and evaluated in order until the first match. When a match is found, the job is either included or excluded from the pipeline, depending on the configuration.
You `cannot` use dotenv `variables created in job` scripts in rules, `because rules are evaluated before any jobs run`.*

So you can not use variables created in one job to decide if a following job should triggered.

In your case why don't you use the `predefined` variable `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`  **directly**?

*CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME*: *The branch or tag name for which project is built*

Change this

```
build_image:
    image: docker:19.03
    services:
        - docker:dind
    stage: release
    rules:
      - if: '$CURRENT_BRANCH == "develop"'
        when: never
```

To

```
build_image:
    image: docker:19.03
    services:
        - docker:dind
    stage: release
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"'
        when: never
```

Answer (score 0):

do you provide the full code of the job `build_image`?
The `build_image` job needs the info.env artifacts of your first job. Can you try to add this?

```
needs:
   - job: '<first-job-name>'
     artifacts: true
```